# SQL Server - Query performs Index Scan instead of Seek

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm in the process of indexing the content of a CMS with Lucene, so I have extended the SQL Server database schema to add an "IsIndexed" bit column, so the Lucene indexer can find a piece of content that hasn't already been indexed.

I added an index to the `Content` table so lookups for the `IsIndexed` column should go faster. This is what the database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Content (
    DocumentId bigint,
    CategoryId bigint,
    Title nvarchar(255),
    AuthorUserId bigint,
    Body nvarchar(MAX),
    IsIndexed bit
)
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId bigint,
    UserName nvarchar(20)
)
```

The following indexes exist:

```
Content (
    PK_Content (Clustered) : DocumentId ASC
    IX_CategoryId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) : CategoryId ASC
    IX_AuthorUserId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) : AuthorUserId ASC
    IX_Indexed_ASC (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) : IsIndexed ASC, DocumentId ASC
    IX_Indexed_DESC (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) : IsIndexed DESC, DocumentId ASC
)

Users (
    PK_Users (Clustered) : UserId
)
```

This is the query used to find nonindexed content:

```
SELECT
    TOP 1
    Content.DocumentId,
    Content.CategoryId,
    Content.Title,
    Content.AuthorUserId,
    Content.Body
    Users.UserName
FROM
    Content
    INNER JOIN Users ON Content.AuthorUserId = Users.UserId
WHERE
    IsIndexed = 0
```

However when I run it the Actual Execution Plan reports a Clustered Index Scan for PK_Content combined with a Clustered Index Seek for PK_Users. The query takes about 300ms to execute.

When I modify the query to remove the Users.UserName field and the Users inner-join, then the query takes about 60ms to run and there is no Clustered Index Scan for PK_Content, only a Clustered Index seek for PK_Content.

I tried this before and after adding a Descending index for the `Content.IsIndexed` column, I also added `Content.DocumentId` to the IX_Indexed indexes, but it made no difference.

What am I doing wrong? I've made all the necessary indexes (and then some). The Content table has hundreds of thousands of rows, similarly for the Users table, so I can't see why the optimiser would choose a scan.

Comment: Has anything been indexed yet? If all (or a majority of) the rows have `IsIndexed` equal to 0, the index is unlikely to be used

Comment: Approximately 30% of all Content rows have IsIndexed = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index on such a low selectivity column (only two values 0 and 1) is always going to be ignored, see [the tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx). One option is to move it as the leftmost key in the clustered index, and make the primary key constraint on DocumentId a non-clustered index:

```
CREATE TABLE Content (
    DocumentId bigint,
    CategoryId bigint,
    Title nvarchar(255),
    AuthorUserId bigint,
    Body nvarchar(MAX),
    IsIndexed bit,
    constraint pk_DocumentId primary key nonclustered (DocumentId)
)

create unique clustered index cdxContent on Content (IsIndexed, DocumentId);
```

Another option is to create a filtered covering index:

```
create unique index nonIndexedContent on Content (DocumentId)
  include (CategoryId, Title, AuthorUserId, Body)
  where IsIndexed = 0;
```

This second option would duplicate a lot of content possibly. Personally, I would go with the first option.

Answer (score 2):

Add an index to Content with both the `IsIndexed` field and the `AuthorUserId` field, it should do a seek then.  Depending on your version of SQL server, you could add an `INCLUDE` statement with the fields you're using in the select to possibly gain more speed.

> IX_Indexed_AuthorUserId (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) : IsIndexed,
>   AuthorUserId

Comment: Thanks. After adding that index the Actual Query Execution plan reports it performed two index seeks and no index scans, however the query still takes about 300ms to run.